# Spark-Java : Display join RDD

Tags: java, join, apache-spark, rdd, keyvaluepair

I am trying to join two pairRDDs  as show below and whereas

lat1 : K,V   -> k-integer , V- Double 
lat2 : K,V   -> k-integer , V- Double

```
   JavaPairRDD<Integer,Tuple2<Double,Double>> latlong = lat.join(long);
```

Am assuming the new RDD will be  K,[V1,V2] and i want to display the new RDD

And also if i want to do operations based on value, what is the way to perform

Please suggest in Spark-Java Api

P.s:  I have seen many answers are in scala but my requirement is to implement in JAVa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Spark documentation:

> When join called on datasets of type (K, V) and (K, W), returns a dataset of (K, (V, W)) pairs with all pairs of elements for each key.

So you are right with this assumption:

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer,Tuple2<Double,Double>> latlong = lat.join(long);
```

When you need to work  with values in `JavaPairRDD`, you can use `#mapValues()` method:

> Pass each value in the key-value pair RDD through a map function without changing the keys; this also retains the original RDD's partitioning.

For displaying the `JavaPairRDD` you can use the same output methods as usual e. g. `#saveAsTextFile()`

---

When you need to map values in `(K, (V, W))` to something else like `(K,V-W)` you can use the mentioned `mapValues()` transformation:

```java
JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> pairs = latlong.mapValues(
        new Function<Tuple2<Double, Double>, String>() {
          @Override
          public String call(Tuple2<Double, Double> value) throws Exception {
            return value._1() + "-" + value._2();
          }
        });
```

Comment: can you suggest how to  transform (K,(V,W)) into (K,V-W) ?

Comment: I edited my post and added an example of `mapValues()` usage.